# Gxt diagramation

Tags: java, gxt

I'm newbie in gxt using java.
I have 8 FramedPanel and I need draw in the next order, but I not have idea how.

FramedPanels numbers:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your desired layout by using VerticalLayoutContainer and HorizontalLayoutContainer.
Don't know if this will be the best solution, but I think it will work!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could not use Gxt, Because Gxt is a frame which is like C/S.
I thought you need use a B/S frame.

Thanks